# Intel PIN: get backtrace on windows

Tags: intel-pin

I'm trying to write a pintool on windows. One thing I want to do is print stack trace after specific instructions. According to the Pin Manual, the [PIN_Backtrace](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98484/Pin/html/group__CONTEXT.html#ga9e0232d7642468e8bfbd4eca00983ecf) is only available on Linux and Mac OS. Is there any equivalent solutions on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shadow stack instead instrumenting all the routines in all the modules using RTN_InsertCall at both IPOINT_BEFORE and IPOINT_AFTER, and modifying the Shadow stack(s) accordingly.

This way you can print the Shadow stack and don't need the backtrace.